# CakePHP and query

Tags: cakephp, between

I wish to write a query like:

```
select * from products where id>5 and (cost>=100 and cost<=500)
```

I tried this:

```
$lastid = $this->request->data("lastid");
$startPrice = $this->request->data("startPrice");
$endPrice = $this->request->data("endPrice");
            
$category = $this->request->data("category");

$conditions = array(
    'and' => array(
        array(                                      
            'Product.cost >= ' => $startPrice,                                  
            'Product.cost <= ' => $endPrice),
            array('Product.id > ' => $lastid,
                    'Product.category' => $category)
            )
);
```

This one is giving me **in** query. What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `AND` option in your query, as it is by default, and your query is only composed with 'ands'

```
$conditions = array(                                 
    'Product.cost >= ' => $startPrice,                                  
    'Product.cost <= ' => $endPrice,
    'Product.id > ' => $lastid,
    'Product.category' => $category
);
```

**EDIT**

If you need an `OR` statement in `category` then you can just add:

```
$conditions = array(                                 
    'Product.cost >= ' => $startPrice,                                  
    'Product.cost <= ' => $endPrice,
    'Product.id > ' => $lastid,
    'OR' => array(
        'Product.category' => $category,
        'Product.category' => anoter_value
    )
);
```

Comment: Correct, thanks Eagle for the quick reply. I was wondering what to write if want to use **or** with category?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without including and in cakephp query. Copy the code and try it and try to see the difference of this and your code

```
$lastid = $this->request->data["lastid"];
$startPrice = $this->request->data["startPrice"];
$endPrice = $this->request->data["endPrice"];
$category = $this->request->data["category"];

$conditions = array(                                
            'Product.cost >= ' => $startPrice,                                  
            'Product.cost <= ' => $endPrice,
            'Product.id > ' => $lastid,
             'Product.category' => $category
);

$result = $this->YourModel->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```